# Any Paid courses on CiviCRM extension development?

Tags: extension, training

Any organizations out there offering a full hands on course on developing extensions for CiviCRM? I'm willing to pay for such a course.

Answer (score 5):

From my personal experience for developing an extension you need to be aware

1. PHP, Mysql, JS etc
2. How CiviCRM works.
3. How data are stored in various database table.
4. Working of QUICKFORM/Smarty or Angular i.e Forms, pages, search, settings etc.
5. When and How CiviCRM hooks are invoked.
6. Logic building, Symphony framework, OOPL...

There are lots of tutorials for above on the internet, its very way to build an extension unless you don't have knowledge/experience about above points.

Answer (score 3):

In the past a CiviCRM sprint would include a developer training but as there are no CiviCRM sprints in this covid period......but I am hopeful there will be one in Berlin in the spring which would potentially also have a developer training.